# Are voltage transients on LTspice simulations significant?

Tags: ltspice, transient-suppression

I (incorrectly*) modeled [this simple answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/219747/39511) in LTspice IV and am seeing seemingly random instantenous voltage spikes up to +/-1kV on the output of the depletion nMOSFET.  Are these real?

If so, are they significant, and if so what standard practices are missing in this design to control them?

[image: Spikey voltage in LTSpice]

<sup>* [Here is the correct model and output, which exhibits no voltage spikes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIEKu.png).  (But I believe the question on the original circuit is still valid.)</sup>

Comment: Which diodes are you using?

Comment: Also, you didn't make the schematic correctly - your drain and source on M1 are swapped.

Comment: You are using the "ideal diode" model which is basically useless.

Comment: @W5VO - Oh ... well, if I do it correctly then it works properly, *and* the transients go away!  The diodes are default -- apparently no breakdown voltage or forward current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The significance that I usually associate depends on the magnitude of the voltage. I think a good measure of how suspicious/skeptical you should be is how many multiples of the expected value you see (and how many ideal components you use).

- Circuit behavior matches expected results: 3/10
- Output voltage exceeds supply voltage by 50%: 4/10
- Output voltage exceeds supply voltage by 110%: 5/10
- Output voltage exceeds supply voltage by 500%: 8/10
- Output voltage is measured in kV or MV: 10/10
- You have to look up the SI prefix for your voltage or current: 11/10

An extremely relevant quote that applies to modeling is

> "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler."

With ideal circuit elements, it is easy to omit a lot of the parasitic effects in a circuit, such as capacitance, inductance and resistance. Ideal models may not switch operating modes smoothly, and abrupt transitions/discontinuities are also sources of more weird solver behavior. Another thing not handled well is multiple high impedance devices in a voltage divider. Another gotcha is operating a model outside its characterized region.

Beware of simulating circuits you don't understand, as you may not understand the expected behavior or be able to spot when it's misbehaving.